# Extract User details from web api auth token in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I am using a webapi project as my auth Server and also resource server. The intention is to access the serivice form an Android app. I also want a web front end which is being written in an MVC app. I originally used the default MVC auth but have moved to web pai handing out tokens. I can recieve the auth token form the webapi service and I am sending the token to the client in a cookie although I may just cache is client side. I currently have the following OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider running:

```
public class CookieOAuthBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        base.RequestToken(context);
        var value = context.Request.Cookies["AuthToken"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            context.Token = value;
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }    
}
```

and in my startup class I have this method:

```
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {

            Provider = new CookieOAuthBearerProvider(),

        });
    }
```

which I call in the Configuration method.

The bit I seem to be missing is how to tap into converting my token into the logged in user. I cant seem to figure out where the deserializtion happens. I have tried changing my configueAuth to:

```
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {

            Provider = new CookieOAuthBearerProvider(),
            AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider()
            {

                OnReceive = receive
            }
        });
    }

    public static Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext> receive = new Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext>(c =>
    {
        c.DeserializeTicket(c.Token);
        c.OwinContext.Environment["Properties"] = c.Ticket.Properties;
    });
```

and my receive method is being called. The AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext has my token attached but the DeserializeTicket is returning null. Can anyone advise what I am missing to get the User details form this token?

UPDATE as per suggested answer below. The Statrup code and OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions now like like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        OAuthOpt = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {

            Provider = new CookieOAuthBearerProvider(),
            AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider()
            {

                OnReceive = receive
            }
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthOpt);
    }

    public static Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext> receive = new Action<AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext>(c =>
    {
        var ticket = OAuthOpt.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(c.Token);

    });

    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthOpt { get; private set; }
}
```

but I am still getting a null value out. Could I be missing some relevant option on the OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

Save the `OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions` you are instantiating inline to a static variable named `OAuthOpt` (or anything you like) in `Startup.Auth` and use the code below wherever you want to retrieve the user information.

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket ticket = Startup.OAuthOpt.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);`
```

I suggest you make use of `Json Web Tokens (JWT)` and customize the token generation using a `CustomOAuthProvider`. [Here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/) is a good resource from Taiseer Joudeh on how to do this. You will have to use this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/) to decode the bearer tokens.

Comment: I wasn't using OAuthorizationServerOptions in Startup Auth. I haven't used the baked in stuff as I wanted to learn how to add this from scratch. At the moment I have only set up UseOAuthBearerAuthentication as I had no need to produce the token in the MVC app. Do I need to set up the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions before I can deserialize the token?

Comment: HI I have tried this and the value out is still null. I have updated the question with the new code. Perhaps I am missing some relevant option from the OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions setup? Both webApi and MVC app are running on the same test machine so don't think it is the machine key deserialization issue.

Comment: What's the value of `c.Token` in your `receive` method?

Comment: Its the protected token value from the web api project: T-ZM7z0VklZbg1aIDzM_vD4_QG3JRJn-gTq8dWGzljyUTieYxB_pKQRV5yjiESP0C295ZC52mE795R4q3dDVTyijWienTVobx25SZ4i1jJsrTsyMJLYYbHsZyJ992pZrFGgGs9gsfHTdwfY2ISgfI_veuuKnisuwjIPmbQNuWbpIORAIYT-Z_BlobVPCru_Rtl74PQivBxDOFcZ1tDHO_9RZmam32e3FRe6Iod3FIN0

Comment: Sorry, I think I got something wrong here. Are you trying to deserialize the token from within the MVC client app?

Comment: Yes so token is produced in seperate webapi web service and token is sent to MVC app. I am trying to deserialize the token in the MVC app. Appreciate I can attach more info to the token that goes to the client but thought it would be nice to tap into the user info - I presumed this was what was serialized into the token

Comment: Selecting as right answer as the suggested alternative is the right way to achieve what I wanted. It will also make things easier when I try to connect form android. Thanks for the pointer.